# Assert if returned value is Redirect or View

Tags: unit-testing, laravel, laravel-4

Let's say I have this controller for authentication:

```
class AuthController extends BaseController
{
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function getLogin()
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            Session::flash('alert-type', 'error');
            Session::flash('alert-message', 'You are already logged in');
            return Redirect::to('home');
        }

        return View::make('auth/login');
    }
}
```

And I have this unit test:

```
public function testGetLoginWithoutLogin()
{
    Auth::shouldReceive('check')->once()->andReturn(false);
    View::shouldReceive('make')->once();

    $userMock = Mockery::mock('Eloquent', 'User');

    $authController = new AuthController($userMock);
    $authController->getLogin();
}
```

How would I make sure here that a View is returned? And in a different unit test with valid login, how would I test it returns a Redirect?

Answer (score 0):

You could check for the type of the return value of `getLogin()`.

**For the redirect**

```
$returnValue = $authController->getLogin();
$this->assertInstanceOf('\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse', $returnValue);
```

**For the view**

```
$returnValue = $authController->getLogin();
$this->assertInstanceOf('\Illuminate\View\View', $returnValue);
```

Comment: In this case that wouldn't be possible, considering View and Redirect are being mocked, and so they wouldn't be instances of either of those classes.

Comment: Puhh honestly I haven't worked a lot with Mockery. But shouldn't you have some way to distinguish between two mock objects?

Comment: @DenizZoeteman have you tested it with instanceof? I thought it wouldn't work too but I just did a little check and it seems that it actually works.

Comment: And how exactly do you mock the view / response? (sorry if this may sound a bit dumb but I'm not very experienced with Mockery)

Answer (score 0):

Use `with()` to check your view is getting the right template:

```
View::shouldReceive('make')->once()->with('auth/login');
```

...and then to check for redirects, there are some [useful assertions that come built in to Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/testing#helper-methods), so:

```
// once you make your simulated request
$this->call('GET', 'URL-that-should-redirect');

// (or simulate a get to the action on your Controller.. )
$this->action('GET', 'Controller@action');

//you can check that a redirect simply happens:
$this->assertResponseStatus(302); // would also work with any HTTP status

// ...or even check that you get redirected to 
// a particular URL ...
$this->assertRedirectedTo('foo');

// ... route ...
$this->assertRedirectedToRoute('route.name');

// ...or controller action
$this->assertRedirectedToAction('Controller@method');
```

Comment: The thing is though, I want to make actual unit tests - as so, test a function as separately as possible from the framework itself. I don't think that's something you can accomplish exactly with using simulated requests...

Comment: @DenizZoeteman You can test a controller's action quite easily.. Would that help? there's a baked-in method for that as well.. I'll update above